# How to pass parameters to spring webflow?

Tags: spring-webflow

First of all, I don't know how can config restful url request for spring webflow,
for example,how can I invoke my webflow when type address:
http://localhost/app/order/edit/1002

It's easy to write spring mvc controller to handle this,but in case of webflow, I don't know how to pass parameters.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try reading request parameter like following.
It processes "http://example.com/message?messageId=3" but when rendering view, the URL changes to something like "http://example.com/message?execution=e1s1".

Flow code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <on-start>
        <evaluate expression="FooWebFlowController.create(flowRequestContext)"
                  result="flowScope.fooModel"/>
    </on-start>

    <view-state id="view" model="fooModel" view="fooView">
    </view-state>
</flow>
```

FooWebFlowController bean:

```java
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext;

@Component
public class FooWebFlowController {

    @Autowired
    private FooDAO fooDAO;

    public Foo create(RequestContext requestContext) {
        String messageId = requestContext.getRequestParameters().get("messageId")
        Foo foo = fooDAO.findByMessagId(messageId);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the [RequestPathFlowExecutorArgumentHandler](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-webflow/1.0.5/spring-webflow-1.0.5-javadoc.jar!/org/springframework/webflow/executor/support/RequestPathFlowExecutorArgumentHandler.html) what you're looking for?

> Flow executor argument handler that
>   extracts arguments from the request
>   path and exposes them in the URL path.
>
> This allows for REST-style URLs to
>   launch flows in the general format:
>   http://${host}/${context
>   path}/${dispatcher path}/${flowId}

```
<bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.executor.mvc.FlowController">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    <property name="argumentHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.executor.support.RequestPathFlowExecutorArgumentHandler" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks,JoseK. I think that is what I want, but still wondering how to use the url like:http://localhost/app/order/edit/1002 to start a flow to eidt order 1002? Could you please give some sample code?

Comment: By the way, I am using spring webflow 2.1.1,I didn't found class org.springframework.webflow.executor.mvc.FlowController and class org.springframework.webflow.executor.support.RequestPathFlowExecutorArgumentHandler in spring-webflow-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Your link is based on 1.0.x,not my version.